# Вычисление цвета по уровню пользователя

Tags: javascript, css

Суть такая. Пользователь со временем получает опыт, пользуясь сайтом. Цвет прогресс бара меняется с уровнем пользователя. Цвет можно задать либо HEX, либо RGB кодом, но я запутался. Я уверен, что подобное можно выразить какой-либо математической формулой, но, видимо, я плохо учил математику.

Уровни идут как очередность чисел: от 1 до бесконечности. Это единственный известный параметр в формуле. Нужно выразить его так, чтобы цвет менялся от одного цвета к другому крайне плавно. То есть если прежний цвет был `(0, 0, 5)`, то следующий уровень изменит его до `(0, 0, 6)`. Но это еще не все. Чтобы избежать черного и белого цветов, я думаю, правильнее будет сделать переход от синего в зеленый, а оттуда в красный. А если цвета закончатся, то пойдут по новой.

Значит, начало в `(0, 0, 255)`, затем зеленый `(0, 255, 0)`, потом красный `(255, 0, 0)`. Но очередная загвоздка в том, что между каждой парой цветов будет так называемый промежуточный цвет. Например, между синим и зеленым будет `(0, 255, 255)`. После чего синий начнет падать в 0.

За последние 3 часа я голову хорошо поломал, исписав листик в совершенно нелогичных догадках о том что нужно сделать. Возможно, кто-то имел дело с подобным и покажет примеры? Или хотя бы подсказки как это сделать в теории?

Comment: 10 раз перечитал не понял в чем суть вопроса...

Comment: @Air каждый уровень пользователя изменяет цвет прогресс бара. Чем выше уровень тем "круче" цвет. Я не знаю как обьяснить лучше, помоему достаточно подробно.

Comment: Это я понял. Я не понял что именно у тебя не получется  и в чем вопрос? Что именно ты не можешь реализовать?

Comment: @Максим Ленский карму начисляют пользователю другие пользователи. Опыт начисляется автоматически за время проведенное на сайте. Каждые X количество опыта повышают уровень, каждый следующий уровень сложнее достать в геометрической прогрессии. Но суть не в этом, а в том что есть уровни 1, 2 ... 256 и эта цифра должна конвертироваться в код цвета (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2) ... (0, 1, 255) и так далее. Если провести ползунок по графическому слайдеру цвета в том же Хроме можно наблюдать как работают переходы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что при таких условиях получается с цветами:

```
 lvl   r   g   b
   0   0   0 255
   1   0   1 255
 254   0 254 255
 255   0 255 255
 256   0 255 254
 509   0 255   1
 510   0 255   0
 511   1 255   0
 764 254 255   0
 765 255 255   0
 766 255 254   0
1019 255   1   0
1020 255   0   0
1021 255   0   1
1274 255   0 254
1275 255   0 255
1276 254   0 255
1529   1   0 255
1530   0   0 255
```

В итоге цикл - 1530 уровней (итераций). Соответственно, для вычисления значений цветов достаточно брать `level % 1530`.

Решение "в лоб":

```js
var colorBlock = document.getElementById("color");
var level = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var levelBase = level % 1530;

  var red = 0;
  if (levelBase >= 511 && levelBase <= 765)
    red = levelBase - 510;
  else if (levelBase >= 766 && levelBase <= 1275)
    red = 255;
  else if (levelBase >= 1276 && levelBase <= 1529)
    red = 1530 - levelBase;

  var green = 0;
  if (levelBase <= 255)
    green = levelBase;
  else if (levelBase <= 765)
    green = 255;
  else if (levelBase <= 1020)
    green = 1020 - levelBase;

  var blue = 0;
  if (levelBase <= 255 || levelBase >= 1276)
    blue = 255;
  else if (levelBase <= 510)
    blue = 510 - levelBase;
  else if (levelBase >= 1021 && levelBase <= 1275)
    blue = levelBase - 1020;

  colorBlock.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
  colorBlock.innerText = level + " " + red + " " + green + " " + blue;
  level++;
}, 10);
```

```css
#color {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="color"></div>
```

---

Можно уменьшить количество строк кода с 34 до 24, вынеся логику определения значения цвета по `levelBase` в отдельную функцию:

```js
var colorBlock = document.getElementById("color");
var level = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var levelBase = level % 1530;
  var red = getColorValue(levelBase, [511, 764], [1276, 1530], [765, 1275]);
  var green = getColorValue(levelBase, [1, 254], [766, 1020], [255, 765]);
  var blue = getColorValue(levelBase, [1021, 1274], [256, 510], [0, 255], [1275, 1529]);
  colorBlock.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
  colorBlock.innerText = level + " " + red + " " + green + " " + blue;
  level++;
}, 10);

function getColorValue(levelBase, incRange, decRange, maxValueRange, maxValueRange2) {
  if (levelBase >= incRange[0] && levelBase <= incRange[1])
    return levelBase - incRange[0];
  if (levelBase >= decRange[0] && levelBase <= decRange[1])
    return decRange[1] - levelBase;
  if (levelBase >= maxValueRange[0] && levelBase <= maxValueRange[1])
    return 255;
  if (maxValueRange2 != null && levelBase >= maxValueRange2[0] && levelBase <= maxValueRange2[1])
    return 255;
  return 0;
}
```

```css
#color {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="color"></div>
```

---

Искусственное "выравнивание" цветов снижает количество строк с 24 до 19, плюсом укоротив некоторые строки кода:

```js
var colorBlock = document.getElementById("color");
var level = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var red = getColorValue((level + 1020) % 1530);
  var green = getColorValue(level % 1530);
  var blue = getColorValue((level + 510) % 1530);
  colorBlock.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
  colorBlock.innerText = level + " " + red + " " + green + " " + blue;
  level++;
}, 10);

function getColorValue(levelBase) {
  if (levelBase <= 254)
    return levelBase;
  if (levelBase <= 765)
    return 255;
  return levelBase <= 1020 ? 1020 - levelBase : 0;
}
```

```css
#color {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="color"></div>
```

Comment: Этого я и боялся.. Тем не менее пока самое точное решение, хотя и не самое красивое. Подожду до завтра, голова не варит, может что придумаю еще.

Comment: @Telion каких-то волшебных функций, дающих решение в одну строку, для такого нет. Единственное - можно попытаться уменьшить количество `if`-ов за счет каких-то формул, но их, во-первых, ещё придумать надо (попытаюсь это сделать сегодня), а во-вторых, их использование ухудшит читаемость кода и, как следствие, усложнит отладку кода.

Comment: нет я полностью понимаю что решение в 1 строку я врядли найду, просто если выйдет уменьшить размер сего кода хотя бы вдвое было бы уже лучше(я понимаю что можно использовать те же строчные операторы IF), а если изобрести формулу то уже даже гордиться есть чем :) Я благодарен за помощь в любом случае, но как сказал, голова не варит, утро вечера мудренее.

Comment: @Telion я количество строк кода во втором примере уменьшил с 34 до 24. Вряд ли получится сделать сильно короче.

Comment: Большое спасибо за старания, этот ответ наиболее точный и достаточно удобный.

Answer (score 6):

Можете воспользоваться `hsl` - первый параметр отвечает за цвет. Правда, я не знаю, как вы представляете себе бесконечное отображение... Ведь цветов то ограниченное количество. Но можно представить что-то типа такого.

```js
function setColorLevels() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${360-i*4-110},100%,50%)`;
    elem.innerText = `level ${i}`;
    content.appendChild(elem);
  }
}
setColorLevels();
```

```html
<content id="content"></content>
```

Comment: Я сказал в вопросе что по окончанию цветов идет по кругу, это вроде работает по кругу. Я проверил все работает и даже можно сдвинуть: https://jsfiddle.net/bs6tqt82/5/. По сути идеально, но все же одна маленькая проблемка, возможно ли как-то легко изменить порядок что бы был синий-зеленый-красный, а не зеленый-синий-красный?

Comment: @Telion Начинаем с синего цвета

Comment: Самый разумный вариант из предложенных в ответах.

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать hsl-цвета

```js
let getTemperatureColor = (value) => ['hsl(', value, ',100%,50%)'].join('');

for (let i = 240; i >= 0; i--) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.style.backgroundColor = getTemperatureColor(i);
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

Если поддерживаемые браузеры позволяют шаблонные строки, то можно упросить еще сильнее.

```js
for (let i = 240; i >= 0; i--) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${i}, 100%,50%)`;
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

Вариант с таймером:

```js
let getTemperatureColor = (value) => ['hsl(', value, ',100%,50%)'].join('');
let i = 240;

setInterval(function() {
  i--;
  document.getElementById('status').style.backgroundColor = getTemperatureColor(i);
}, 25);
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Как и у другого товарища ответившиго на вопрос у вас тоже очередность цветов не такая как я задумывал. Переспрошу: нельзя ли изменить очередность до синий-зеленый-красный? Во всем остальном идеально. А, стоп, если инвертировать то наверное можно...

Comment: @Telion, поправил, если поиграться со значениями диапазона для цикла, с 200 до 400 получается как раз синий-зеленый-красный

Comment: @Regent, этого можно добиться заменив 400 на большее число, точно не скажу сколько, надо поиграться со значением.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin а ещё, я так понимаю, у вас не все 1530 цветов получаются? Не то чтобы я бы на практике стал упираться за использование именно всех требуемых цветов, но всё же.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, у синего цвета Hue-координата равна **240** (360*0.6666), никак не 200.

Comment: @yar85, там в коде формула вычислялась, по ней 200 - преобразовывалось в 240, сейчас переделал, стало даже лучше, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: @Regent, угу, фиолетовые отсутствуют. Должно быть так: http://jsbin.com/fugoyaciro/edit?js,output `p.s.:` 1530 цветов не будет, так как этим алгоритмом выводятся только чистые цвета (коих 360), а б**о**льшая часть из возможных хтмл-цветов - это оттенки.